# Passing parameter to a kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, parameter-passing, kernel-module

I have some custom hardware that uses a kernel module called `foo.ko`. This has to be `insmod` from the Linux kernel.

Is there is a way to pass a parameter to the kernel module during insmod, something like:

```
insmod foo.ko <parameter>
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Name the parameters like this:

```
insmod foo.ko mystring="bebop" mybyte=255
```

[From Passing Command Line Arguments to a Module : The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x354.htm)

Answer (score 6):

You can set any needed parameters at load time this way:

```
insmod param_name=param_value
```

and set it in your source code this way:

```
module_param(param_name, param_type, permission);
```

param types supported:

```
int -> integer value
charp -> character pointer
....
```

Permission is a mask like `S_IRUGO`, you may need to check `moduleparam.h`.

Comment: A snippet of the code would be more helpful !